# Lost and damaged passport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, dubai, passport-renewals, lost-documents

I currently have a visa on my lost passport to Dubai. I want to get a new one but the numbers will not be the same though I was told that the new one will have a reflection of the old one in it. Would this be a sort of problem for me? It's actually an employment visa.

Comment: To clarify: you have a work visa for Dubai in a passport you lost. You now want to get a replacement passport and are wondering if the visa will still be valid or not. Please add as many details as possible to your question. It makes it easier to answer.

Comment: And to protect yourself and your privacy, you don't need to include any personal details, such as email or picture. Those who respond will do so right here, either asking for additional details in comment, or by adding an answer, below.

Comment: Do you have a passport number written on your visa?

Comment: Yes I do have a passport number written on my visa because that was the first information on my passport I sent to my employer. All the answers are useful. To joErnano, yes, that's exactly what happened my passport. Sorry if my question wasn't hitting my point.